# Silex match GET but no POST

Tags: php, rest, post, http-status-code-404, silex

Something extremely unusual is happening to me. I have a simple REST API application that handle everything with ControllerProviders. So, in controllers.php I defined

```
$app->mount('/login', new Portcontrol\Provider\Controller\LoginControllerProvider);
$app->mount('/board', new Portcontrol\Provider\Controller\BoardControllerProvider);
$app->mount('/group', new Portcontrol\Provider\Controller\GroupControllerProvider);
```

Next, for example I created the LoginControllerProvider in this manner:

```
public function connect(Application $app)
{
    $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

    $controllers->match('/', 'Portcontrol\Controller\Login\LoginController::indexAction');

    return $controllers;
}
```

The stranger thing is that when I request with a GET, the controller respons **BUT** when I request a *POST* the engine say to me that is not found. Is the same file and I actually need the POST method because I expect the idToken of Google to authenticate.
I try to change match to post, but is the same, the result of POST request is the default Silex Page not found.

This is a fragment of my LoginController:

```
    class LoginController{

        public function indexAction(Application $app, Request $request){
            Constants::resetlog("/login");

            $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
            $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());

            if ($request->request->get('idToken')){
                Constants::log("/login: G");

                /*
                $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => Constants::client_id()]);
                $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($request->request->get("idToken"));            
                */

                //PAYLOAD TO TEST WITHOUT GOING TO GOOGLE        
                $payload = Constants::test_payload();

                if ($payload) {
                    if ($this->toDatabase($payload, $request->request->get('serverAuthCode')))
                        return $this->loginSuccessResponse($request->request->get('serverAuthCode'));
                }
            }
            return Constants::failResponse();
        }
```

Comment: hi do you have this hosted somewhere to test

Comment: Yes, it is allocated in a VM Amazon Linux over AWS: http://ec2-52-14-147-102.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/portcontrol/web/login